# looking for an alternative verb: computing the ratio of A and B

Tags: word-request, mathematics

Maybe this is the native German speaker in me, but I am looking for an alternative verb to use, when I want to write:

*We compute the ratio of A and B.*

I am not happy with the verbs *to compute/to calculate* since they imply using concrete numbers, whereas, at this stage I am doing symbolic math. After writing down the ratio of A and B, the ratio will by simplified, but no numerical values will be computed.

I am writing a report, and in the theory section I want to describe how I derived a ratio X from the initial ratio of A and B.

In German, I would say *A und B ins Verhältnis setzen*, which carries a more general meaning than mere math. Thus, I am looking for a verb, that carries a similar, general meaning.

Comment: When I studied maths, I used *find the ratio*. This doesn't necessarily mean finding exact quantities.

Comment: Side note:  I would say _"We find the ratio of A **to** B"_ rather than _"....A **and** B."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find *determine* to be useful here:

> **determine** *v*
>   1.
>   a. To establish or ascertain definitely, as after consideration, investigation, or calculation: *determined the easiest way to reach the summit*.

It has the added benefit of including the possibility of calculation while not specifically requiring that.

Answer (score 0):

To find a ratio between two numbers [very used]

Google hits in standard texts:

> [to find a ratio](https://www.google.com/search?ei=S3mSW8ekA8W-ggeDo4igDg&q=%22to%20find%20a%20ratio%22&oq=%22to%20find%20a%20ratio%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l10.57069.65884..66253...0.0..0.78.386.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30.i40xkDNGRDw)